# ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database

Tags: mysql

I am getting the following error while connecting MySQL with Visual Studio Code (version 1.75):

> ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'default'

See screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: read `Unknown database "default"` quite literally. There is no database created called "default".

Comment: If no need to put some database in that field, use "information_schema" which is built in, until you create a real database.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have not created the local database with a DB name `default`. Just create it first, then try again.